# QGIS 3.0.3 (and 3.2.0) crashes on start. Ubuntu 16.04, conda environment

Tags: qgis, error, qgis-3, ubuntu, conda

I am trying to QGIS in a conda environment, python 3.6.5, conda 4.5.8, Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial. It crashes upon start-up without even loading all the way. I have tried both QGIS 3.0.3 and 3.2.0 (3.2.0 is a dev version), and both return a massive error. It's over 500 lines long, the start of it is below and the rest if it is in this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/DeU2qbev

```
QGIS died on signal 11[New LWP 4436]
[New LWP 4437]
[New LWP 4439]
[New LWP 4440]
[New LWP 4442]
[New LWP 4446]
[New LWP 4447]
[New LWP 4449]
[New LWP 4450]
[New LWP 4451]
[New LWP 4452]
[New LWP 4453]
[New LWP 4454]
[New LWP 4455]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007f05b76f50cb in __GI___waitpid (pid=4456, stat_loc=0x7fffb213fb3c, options=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:29
29  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f05a713f7c0 (LWP 4435))]
#0  0x00007f05b76f50cb in __GI___waitpid (pid=4456, stat_loc=0x7fffb213fb3c, options=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:29
        resultvar = 18446744073709551104
        sc_cancel_oldtype = 0
#1  0x00000000004074f7 in qgisCrash(int) ()
No symbol table info available.
#2  <signal handler called>
No locals.
#3  PyType_IsSubtype (a=0x626f6174656d5f74, b=0x7f052c8c8e80) at Objects/typeobject.c:1357
        mro = 0x1
#4  0x00007f052c6bee91 in ?? () from /home/mee/miniconda2/envs/qgis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sip.so
    No symbol table info available.
    #5  0x00007f052c6bf715 in ?? () from /home/mee/miniconda2/envs/qgis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sip.so
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007f052c388cdd in qpycore_init() () from /home/mee/miniconda2/envs/qgis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00007f052c35fbfc in PyInit_QtCore () from /home/mee/miniconda2/envs/qgis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x00007f052d1c80d7 in _PyImport_LoadDynamicModuleWithSpec (spec=spec@entry=0x7f052c905780, fp=fp@entry=0x0) at ./Python/importdl.c:159
        pathbytes = <optimized out>
        name_unicode = 0x7f052c9049f0
        name = <optimized out>
        path = 0x7f052c988cb0
        m = 0x0
        name_buf = 0x7f052c945cd0 "QtCore"
        hook_prefix = 0x7f052d27f6a6 "PyInit"
        oldcontext = 0x0
        exportfunc = 0x7f052c35fb20 <PyInit_QtCore>
        def = <optimized out>
        p0 = 0x7f052c35fb20 <PyInit_QtCore>
#9  0x00007f052d1c621b in _imp_create_dynamic_impl (module=<optimized out>, file=<optimized out>, spec=0x7f052c905780) at Python/import.c:1982
        mod = 0x0
        name = 0x7f052c9049f0
        path = 0x7f052c988cb0
        fp = 0x0
#10 _imp_create_dynamic (module=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>) at Python/clinic/import.c.h:289
        return_value = 0x0
        spec = 0x7f052c905780
        file = 0x0
#11 0x00007f052d1091b9 in PyCFunction_Call (func=func@entry=0x7f052c9feee8, args=args@entry=0x7f052c9ebd30, kwds=kwds@entry=0x7f052c906c18) at Objects/methodobject.c:114
        f = 0x7f052c9feee8
        meth = 0x7f052d1c6110 <_imp_create_dynamic>
        self = 0x7f052c9fa5e8
        arg = <optimized out>
        res = <optimized out>
        size = <optimized out>
        flags = 1
#12 0x00007f052d1a9be8 in do_call_core (kwdict=0x7f052c906c18, callargs=0x7f052c9ebd30, func=0x7f052c9feee8) at Python/ceval.c:5089
        result = <optimized out>
        tstate = <optimized out>
#13 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault (f=<optimized out>, throwflag=<optimized out>) at Python/ceval.c:3391
        func = 0x7f052c9feee8
        callargs = 0x7f052c9ebd30
        kwargs = 0x7f052c906c18
        stack_pointer = 0x7f052c94dac8
        next_instr = 0x7f057400b268
        opcode = <optimized out>
        oparg = <optimized out>
        why = <optimized out>
        fastlocals = <optimized out>
        freevars = <optimized out>
        retval = 0x0
        tstate = <optimized out>
        co = <optimized out>
        instr_ub = -1
        instr_lb = 0
        instr_prev = -1
        first_instr = <optimized out>
        names = <optimized out>
        consts = <optimized out>
        opcode_targets = {0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a3ffc <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+5052>, 0x7f052d1a7a17 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+19927>, 0x7f052d1a75e6 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+18854>, 0x7f052d1a44f9 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+6329>, 0x7f052d1a449e <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+6238>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a445f <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+6175>, 0x7f052d1a43df <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+6047>, 0x7f052d1a4365 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+5925>, 0x7f052d1a42d9 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+5785>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a7389 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+18249>, 0x7f052d1a6b88 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+16200>, 0x7f052d1a4f96 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+9046>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a4ef2 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+8882>, 0x7f052d1a4e55 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+8725>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a4d8c <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+8524>, 0x7f052d1a4cc3 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+8323>, 0x7f052d1a4c26 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+8166>, 0x7f052d1a4b89 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+8009>, 0x7f052d1a4aec <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+7852>, 0x7f052d1a4a4f <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+7695>, 0x7f052d1a49b2 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+7538>, 0x7f052d1a4915 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+7381>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000> <repeats 20 times>, 0x7f052d1a4837 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+7159>, 0x7f052d1a477e <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+6974>, 0x7f052d1a46aa <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+6762>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a45e1 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+6561>, 0x7f052d1a4544 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+6404>, 0x7f052d1a423c <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+5628>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a419f <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+5471>, 0x7f052d1a40e9 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+5289>, 0x7f052d1a404f <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+5135>, 0x7f052d1a692d <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+15597>, 0x7f052d1a6890 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+15440>, 0x7f052d1a3a06 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+3526>, 0x7f052d1a3969 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+3369>, 0x7f052d1a38cc <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+3212>, 0x7f052d1a3828 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+3048>, 0x7f052d1a5bc9 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+12169>, 0x7f052d1a5b35 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+12021>, 0x7f052d1a5a90 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+11856>, 0x7f052d1a59fa <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+11706>, 0x7f052d1a56e8 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+10920>, 0x7f052d1a565e <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+10782>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a55c1 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+10625>, 0x7f052d1a5524 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+10468>, 0x7f052d1a5946 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+11526>, 0x7f052d1a58a9 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+11369>, 0x7f052d1a580c <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+11212>, 0x7f052d1a5801 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+11201>, 0x7f052d1a3ef1 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+4785>, 0x7f052d1a3e3b <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+4603>, 0x7f052d1a59e3 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+11683>, 0x7f052d1a3c30 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+4080>, 0x7f052d1a525d <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+9757>, 0x7f052d1a5231 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+9713>, 0x7f052d1a51df <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+9631>, 0x7f052d1a513c <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+9468>, 0x7f052d1a50d7 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+9367>, 0x7f052d1a5033 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+9203>, 0x7f052d1a61ee <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+13742>, 0x7f052d1a60f0 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+13488>, 0x7f052d1a607f <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+13375>, 0x7f052d1a5f99 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+13145>, 0x7f052d1a5ef2 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+12978>, 0x7f052d1a5e62 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+12834>, 0x7f052d1a5dd0 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+12688>, 0x7f052d1a745d <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+18461>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a7409 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+18377>, 0x7f052d1a6a12 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+15826>, 0x7f052d1a69ca <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+15754>, 0x7f052d1a6aaa <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+15978>, 0x7f052d1a5d50 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+12560>, 0x7f052d1a5cc9 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+12425>, 0x7f052d1a5c43 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+12291>, 0x7f052d1a6f67 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+17191>, 0x7f052d1a775b <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+19227>, 0x7f052d1a7990 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+19792>, 0x7f052d1a74d1 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+18577>, 0x7f052d1a549a <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+10330>, 0x7f052d1a5413 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+10195>, 0x7f052d1a53bb <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+10107>, 0x7f052d1a530e <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+9934>, 0x7f052d1a6265 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+13861>, 0x7f052d1a7637 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+18935>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a773a <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+19194>, 0x7f052d1aa1de <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+30110>, 0x7f052d1a3756 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+2838>, 0x7f052d1a3756 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+2838>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a757e <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+18750>, 0x7f052d1a7514 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+18644>, 0x7f052d1a76c1 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+19073>, 0x7f052d1a6e63 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+16931>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a6e2b <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+16875>, 0x7f052d1a6daf <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+16751>, 0x7f052d1a7034 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+17396>, 0x7f052d1a6f96 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+17238>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a7322 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+18146>, 0x7f052d1a6310 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+14032>, 0x7f052d1a6c90 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+16464>, 0x7f052d1a6c25 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+16357>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000>, 0x7f052d1a67f8 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+15288>, 0x7f052d1a6645 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+14853>, 0x7f052d1a6537 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+14583>, 0x7f052d1a651c <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+14556>, 0x7f052d1a6490 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+14416>, 0x7f052d1a6404 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+14276>, 0x7f052d1a6d0a <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+16586>, 0x7f052d1a3aa3 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+3683>, 0x7f052d1a36b7 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+2679>, 0x7f052d1a6af5 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+16053>, 0x7f052d1a3b3b <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+3835>, 0x7f052d1a36b7 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+2679>, 0x7f052d1a7157 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+17687>, 0x7f052d1a72a3 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+18019>, 0x7f052d1a71d8 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+17816>, 0x7f052d1a78c1 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+19585>, 0x7f052d1a6384 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+14148>, 0x7f052d1a9d72 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+28978>, 0x7f052d1a7a60 <_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+20000> <repeats 97 times>}
```

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: possibly this is a known, open issue - that stack trace looks [very similar to this one](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17908).